# Azure JWT Token Key Rotation

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory

Azure makes the public keys for jwt tokens available here:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys

Are these keys rotated and replaced? If so how frequently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that frequency is disclosed as public information.

Here is related information from Microsoft Docs.

[Signing key rollover in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover)

> For security purposes, Azure AD’s signing key rolls on a periodic
>   basis and, in the case of an emergency, could be rolled over
>   immediately. Any application that integrates with Azure AD should be
>   prepared to handle a key rollover event no matter how frequently it
>   may occur.

Comment: They say it's a good practice to check for update at least every 24h

Comment: Does that imply that a key synced at hour 0 will be at least valid for 24 hours? That must mean that 2 or more keys would be valid for at least 24 hours. Otherwise if I synced keys just before they rotated, my application would still break until the next sync.

Comment: Oh yes: "There's always more than one valid key available in the OpenID Connect discovery document and the federation metadata document. Your application should be prepared to use any and all of the keys specified in the document, since one key may be rolled soon, another may be its replacement, and so forth"